# putting a ball inside a circle

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to make a simple game which contains a circle and a ball inside it. I want to move the small ball around in this circle. So far I have created the circle and am able to put the ball (another small circle) on the screen.

My problem is when I attach a physics body on the ball, it drops out of the screen and does not stop on the circle's edge.

How would I be able to make it so the ball bounces at the edge of the circle, so it just bounces INSIDE the circle, if I were to put a velocity on the ball?

this is my code so far to create the ball/circle:

```
local circle = display.newCircle (display.contentWidth/1.95,display.contentWidth/1.2,500)
circle:setFillColor(0,.3, .35, 1) --This will set the fill color to transparent
circle.strokeWidth = 7 --This is the width of the outline of the circle
circle:setStrokeColor(.1,1,1) --This is the color of the outline

local scoreCircle = display.newCircle (display.contentWidth/1.95,display.contentWidth/1.2,70)
scoreCircle:setFillColor(0, .3, .3, 1) --This will set the fill color to transparent
scoreCircle.strokeWidth = 7 --This is the width of the outline of the circle
scoreCircle:setStrokeColor(.1,1,1) --This is the color of the outline
```

Comment: Do you have to use a physics body. Maybe it would be simpler if you did the physics by hand.

Comment: The thing I am not sure is. Im not sure how to make it so the edges of the circle is something 'physical', as in, the ball bounces once the ball hits the edges of the circle

Comment: Are you using the physics module?

Comment: i have tried it. and it seems that the ball that was in the circle just falls straight through the circle.

Comment: If you make two physics bodies out of circles, they'll collide with each other at their boundaries. There's no way to tell box2d that you want the circle to be *hollow*. You'll have to create a bunch of bodies and arrange them into a circle. Or do the physics calculations yourself.

Comment: ah okay. that was what i was afraid to do. i was wondering, if i can somehow find the radius of the circle and then use that as a way to make it bounce if the ball goes over that certain radius. is there a way to do that?

Comment: or, would i be able to import a picture of a hollow circle, and let that act as a physical body?

Comment: "somehow find the radius"? You supplied the radius.

Comment: @Mud instead of a bunch of bodies, could a "C" shape do the job.